# what are .PHT files

Tags: php

According to this advisory, .pht files can be used to execute PHP code:https://www.portcullis-security.com/security-research-and-downloads/security-advisories/cve-2015-5074/

However, I am unable to find much information on this file format. I am also unable to get an Apache server running PHP to execute this file.

Does anyone have more information regarding this file format?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not used much. This is a quote from [file-extensions.org](http://www.file-extensions.org/pht-file-extension)

> The PHT file stores HTML page that includes a PHP script, dynamically generates HTML, often by accessing database information.
>   PHT seems to be very little used format.

These days, you're more likely to see .phtml files. Where there is a mix of PHP and HTML in the file, it still needs to be parsed by the PHP processor to create the right output.

I am not aware of a web server that handles PHT files with the PHP handler by default. Given their nature it's much more likely that they would be templates, included from another PHP file.

In this use case, the included file can have any extension the developer desires and there could be no official association.